# Symfony2 minify without java or node

Tags: symfony, minify

I do not have access to java or node on my shared host.  Is there a way to minify server side, so I can continue to use assetic, without these engines?  Uglify uses node and yui-compressor (deprecated anyway) uses java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There seem to be 2 filters using only PHP code:

- [CssMinFilter](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Filter/CssMinFilter.php)
- [JSMinPlusFilter](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Filter/JSMinPlusFilter.php)

You will need to install the [minify](https://github.com/mrclay/minify) php library through composer, and then use the `cssmin` and `jsminplus` assetic filters.

Comment: I will give that a shot thanks!  I don't know why I couldn't find that info on Google :-(

Answer (score 3):

Just for clarify the steps:

1. `composer require mrclay/minify`
2. In symfony `app/config/config.yml` add to assetic config:

   `# some stuff
   assetic:
       filters:
           # possible another filters
           minifycsscompressor: ~
           jsminplus: ~`

   3. In twig:

   `{% stylesheets
       <your assets>
       filter='minifycsscompressor'
    %}
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
     {% endstylesheets %}`

   `{% javascripts
          <your assets>
          filter='jsminplus'
    %}
          <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}`

Comment: I have tried this and when I do an assetic dump I get the following:  
`Attempted to load class "JSMinPlus" from the global namespace.  
Did you forget a "use" statement?` Minify is installed through composer fine (I can see the code in the vendor directory), do we need to register it in symfony in  AppKernel.php (normally you use new to add a bundle) or something like that?

Comment: so after running into this issue myself, it appears that mrclay's github repo has a version 3 that appears to have namespaced the classes.  You'll need to install one of the 2.x versions of the library and then it will work as expected.  change your composer.json to be: "mrclay/minify": "^2.3"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but I would like to add a small correction to @AdrianBrault's answer for anyone who stumbles onto this.

When installing the said minify library, you need to use the `minifycsscompressor` filter, which uses the [MinifyCssCompressorFilter](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Filter/MinifyCssCompressorFilter.php) class. The `cssmin` uses a different minification library.

Comment: Thank, cssminify didn't worked, but minifycsscompressor did.